# with-redefs doesn't redefine my function

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, compojure

I have a test:

```
(ns gui-proxy.handler-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [ring.mock.request :as mock]
            [gui-proxy.handler :as handler]))

(deftest test-app
  (testing "not-found route"
        (with-redefs-fn [handler/log-request  (fn [type url] (str ""))]
          (let [response (handler/app (mock/request :get "/invalid"))]
            (is (= (:status response) 404))))))
```

and the code that are under test:

```
(ns gui-proxy.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]
            [clj-http.client :as client]
            [gui-proxy.db :as db]))

(defn log-request [type url]
    (db/insert-request-info type url))

(defn log-error []
    (log-request ":fail" "fail"))
    "gui-proxy - File not found")

(defroutes app-routes
    (route/not-found (log-error)))
```

So, basically i'd like to stop the call to the database-namespace, but i end upp in a fat database exeception stacktrace...

What is wrong?

Comment: Your `log-error` function looks like a copy&paste&edit error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[with-redefs-fn](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs-fn) takes a map of bindings, not a vector. Note that the examples at clojuredocs use the `#'` reader macro to refer to the Var, so summing up you could try

```
(deftest test-app
  (testing "not-found route"
        (with-redefs-fn {#'handler/log-request  (fn [type url] (str ""))}
          (let [response (handler/app (mock/request :get "/invalid"))]
            (is (= (:status response) 404))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `with-redefs` it should match your usage.

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs